# How do I give cmd permissions to apache?

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I'm working on a php application that pulls github repositories to the server. Github webhooks call the php files.

I want to execute a cmd command using php. I assume I need apache permissions but I don't know how to give them.

The php code below creates an `mkdir.bat` and a `gitclone.bat` and runs them. The `mkdir` runs successfully, it creates an empty folder, but the `gitclone` doesn't create any folders or files. When I run the `gitclone` manually it does create folders and files.

```
file_put_contents("mkdir.bat", "mkdir test");
exec("mkdir.bat");

file_put_contents("gitclone.bat", "git clone https://github.com/gutyina700/WPTG.git");
exec("gitclone.bat");
```

Comment: cant you use `exec` function?

Comment: I can use the php exec function for starting a bat that has a simple command like mkdir, but I can't use it for git clone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I executed your code in my computer

```
file_put_contents("gitclone.bat", "git clone https://github.com/gutyina700/WPTG.git");
exec("gitclone.bat 2>&1",$o);
print_r($o);
```

the extra code is to check the output from cmd and it returned "git command not exsists"
so you only have to add a line as

```
<?php
putenv("PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\cmd");
file_put_contents("gitclone.bat", "git clone https://github.com/gutyina700/WPTG.git");
exec("gitclone.bat 2>&1",$o);
print_r($o);
?>
```

This was working properly.